# How to update database on select dropdown list using Ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Looking for a way where I can update a database whwnever I select anything in dropdpwn. 
So if I select A from dropdown that value should save in database using Ajax.

Thanks,

Comment: Well do you just want to send a form using AJAX whenever this event happens or do you want to load data as well? And are you using prototype or jQuery?

Comment: surely ..you must state whether drop down is in form...

Comment: I am using Jquery , dropdown is in partial form.

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that you have drop drop boxes in a form.

Firstly for all the drop down give the same class name and onchange of the options i have submitted the form.Put this code in your file and check.You can pass the options in drop_down_options and also params if any.

```
<%= form_for(@entry, :url => entries_path, :html => {:id => 'drop_down_form', :method => 'GET'}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :first_d_down ,options_for_select(drop_down_options, params),{:include_blank => 'first value'},{:class => 'drop_down',:style =>"width:200px;"}%>
<%end%>

   $('.drop_down').change(function(){
     $('#drop_down_form').submit();
   return false;
   })
```

Include this in script tag

Hope it helps ,do reply if any further queries

Thanx

Comment: This is exactly what i am using in script " $('#Tags').change(function(){
                                              alert("hi");
                                              $('#Tags').submit();
                                              return false;
                                            }) ;" and